# Cache folder for the darktable-generate-cache

Tags: troubleshooting

`darktable-generate-cache` generates missing thumbnails when your computer is in idle. That is what the manual says.

Here is my question:

1. How to change the cache folder where the `darktable-generate-cache` generates?

   I need to know it since I'm using a different cache folder rather than default one.
2. I don't understand the part "when your computer is in idle."

   Is it actually working without closing the application itself? Since Idle or not the database file is locked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. From the [Darktable manual](https://www.darktable.org/usermanual/en/overview_chapter.html#darktable_generate_cache_commandline_parameters):

```
darktable-generate-cache --core --cachedir <directory>
```

2. I'm not sure what they mean by "when your computer is in idle" – possibly it's just meant to suggest you run this program when you're not otherwise using the CPU?

Comment: I didn't understand the manpage says about the --core option. Thanks to your answer, now I understand it.